# Critical Maximum current for a DC-DC Buck Converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, formula-derivation

I was wondering how one would go about the derivation for the output to input voltage ratio for a DC-DC Buck converter given the critical max current that is found to be 
$$ I_{crit} = \frac{V_{in}T}{8L} $$
The final result of the output to input voltage ratio is
$$ \frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}} = \frac{D^{2}}{D^2 + \frac{I_{load}}{4I_{crit}}}$$

Edit: For clarification: T is the period and L is the inductance and D is the duty cycle and we assume the system to be in discontinuous current mode

Comment: DCM or CCM? What is T and what is L and why is there a critical value of output current. Many things you should explain.

Comment: T is the period and L is the inductance and D is the duty cycle and we assume the system to be in discountinous current mode.

Comment: And \$I_{crit}\$? Is it at the boundary condition?

Comment: @Andyaka $$I_{crit} $$ is at the boundary condition